# Empty Labels by querying with SPARQL in WikiData

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Update: This question is linked to the other question via [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835069/querying-property-without-value-with-sparql-in-wikidata) because it is about the same output data.

I have got a list of 1200 geographic enties like cities, lakes oder mountains as strings. I would like to enrich these enties with the authority file WikiData ID. This works but as result I get sometimes more than one WikiDataID suggestion. I need to define the right one by the apperance of any country (it doesn't matter which one) in the Statements as a constraint.

As an example I tried the city Karlsruhe. For the string "Karlsruhe" I get five results. In this case I choose the ID Q1040 (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1040).
Now I have got the problem that I don't know how to query the altLabel (Also konwn as) and the Label in Englisch, German and French.
With the current code I get empty entries for the altLabel and the Labels although there are altLabels and Labels (see WikiData).
I think I have just used the wrong order of the code lines.
Can someone help me with the right order?

Thank you very much for your help!

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?altLabel ?label_en ?label_de ? 
label_fr WHERE { 
?item rdfs:label "Karlsruhe"@de.
?item wdt:P17 [] .

optional {
?item skos:altLabel ?altLabel.
?item rdfs:label ?label_de FILTER((LANG(?label_de)) = "de") .
?item rdfs:label ?label_en FILTER((LANG(?label_en)) = "en") .
?item rdfs:label ?label_fr FILTER((LANG(?label_fr)) = "fr") .
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel), ?item))
}
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language " 
[AUTO_LANGUAGE],de, en, fr". }
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20skos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0Aprefix%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FaltLabel%20%3Flabel_en%20%3Flabel_de%20%3Flabel_fr%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Karlsruhe%22%40de.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%23%20P17%20is%20a%20country%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP17%20%5B%5D%20.%0A%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3FaltLabel.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_de%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3Flabel_de%29%29%20%3D%20%22de%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_en%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3Flabel_en%29%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel_fr%20FILTER%28%28LANG%28%3Flabel_fr%29%29%20%3D%20%22fr%22%29%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FaltLabel%29%2C%20%3Fitem%29%29%0A%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cde%2C%20en%2C%20fr%22.%20%7D%0A%0A%0A%7D%20%0Alimit%2010)

Comment: this FILTER is weird: `FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel), ?item))` the lanague is not given but the `item` variable for whatever reason. If you use the LANGMATCHES function, it should be `FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel), "en"))` for English for example.

Comment: and you're also slightly misusing the OPTIONAL pattern. If there is for example no German label, the whole OPTIONAL clause will be empty. Correct usage would be `optional {
    ?item skos:altLabel ?altLabel.
    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel), "en"))
  }
  optional {?item rdfs:label ?label_de FILTER((LANG(?label_de)) = "de") }
  optional { ?item rdfs:label ?label_en FILTER((LANG(?label_en)) = "en") }
  optional { ?item rdfs:label ?label_fr FILTER((LANG(?label_fr)) = "fr") }`

Comment: But, as you can see, the alternative label is **not** availble for English. You also can see this in the web page of Karlsruhe. Only for German and French there is such an alias.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Querying property without value with SPARQL in WikiData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835069/querying-property-without-value-with-sparql-in-wikidata)

Comment: This is so very homework looking... as is its clone, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835069/querying-property-without-value-with-sparql-in-wikidata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked for my project:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT DISTINCT  * 

WHERE {
  ?item rdfs:label "Karlsruhe"@de.   

  ?item rdfs:label ?label_de.
  FILTER((LANG(?label_de)) = "de").

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE], de, en, fr". }

    bind(if(exists{?item wdt:P17 []}, "yes", "no") as ?country_)

  optional {

      ?item rdfs:label ?label_en.     
      FILTER((LANG(?label_en)) = "en").      
      ?item rdfs:label ?label_fr.  
      FILTER((LANG(?label_fr)) = "fr").

    ?item skos:altLabel ?altLabel_de.
    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel_de), "de"))
    optional {
    ?item skos:altLabel ?altLabel_en.
    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel_en), "en"))
      }
    optional {
    ?item skos:altLabel ?altLabel_fr.
    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?altLabel_fr), "fr"))
      }
  }  
} 
order by ?item
```